# Datacite - You have to register metadata first! HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed

Tags: curl, doi

After migrating our repository I want re-register existing dois to make them redirect to our new repository.
Unfortunatly the [datacite documentation](https://support.datacite.org/docs/mds-2) didn't work for me. This is the example call from documentation:

```
# PUT /doi
$ curl -H "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" -X PUT --user username:password -d "$(printf 'doi=10.5072/JQX3-61AT\nurl=http://example.org/')" https://mds.test.datacite.org/doi/10.5072/JQX3-61AT
```

I changed the `servern`,  `doi` and `url` part in accordance to my setup. All DOIs are already registered and associated with metadata. But I got only

```
HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed
```

This usually happens if a DOI is not associated with a metadata stream. But in my case **the DOI has metadata**.

Working through the examples on the docu. This does not happen on the test instance **it only happens in production**.

**Is there a way to re-register DOI redirects on datacite using curl?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After skipping through datacite source code I found a solution:

It is also possible to pass parameters as query parameters

```
curl -XPUT -uusername:password "https://mds.datacite.org/doi/?doi=10.5072/JQX3-61AT&url=https://myserver/url/for/10.5072/JQX3-61AT" -d"" -H"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  -i
```

datacite now returns

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
```

And the redirect points to our new server.